# How to log cypress.io, cy.request into a file

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I have the following working code to log the response. Now, trying to figure out a way to log the request. How can we log it? It just returns undefined.

I tried to have log=true on cy.request, but it's logging only on the browser console. Would be best to write to a file.

```js
it('Query Endpoint', () => {
    request = cy.request(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/service', 
            auth: {
                username: Cypress.env('username'),
                password: Cypress.env('password')
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: {},
            log: true
        })
    .should((response) => {
        
        cy.log(request.body) // <-- how can you log the request?
        cy.writeFile('cypress/responses/api-service.json', request.body) // <-- how can you log the request?

        expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        cy.writeFile('cypress/responses/api-service.json', response.body)
    })

})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to use `.then` instead of `should` and the `request` should resolve inside promise. It is writing a file for me inside the fixture folder. But in the answer I left as the same `path` as given in your question.

```
it('Query Endpoint', () => {
        cy.request(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/service', 
                auth: {
                    username: Cypress.env('username'),
                    password: Cypress.env('password')
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: {}
            })
            .then((request) => {
                const someRequest =  JSON.stringify(request);
                cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/api-service.json', someRequest)
                //...rest of the code 
          })

    })
```